# Intel Centrino 6235 no longer detected Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: 16.04, thinkpad, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

My wifi has always worked out of the box on my Thinkpad T440p since Ubuntu 14.04. I have always done release upgrades. About two months ago i noticed my pc would not connect to my work wifi even though the password was correct. It tries connecting and then fails but my smartphone connects to that same wifi network.

Thinking it might be a problem with Ubuntu, I ran some commands including `sudo ifconfig wlan0 down` and `sudo iwlwifi wlan0 power off`.
I had SIOCSI errors when trying to bring up the wlan0 interface via ifconfig. Thinking I may have a driver issue, I reinstalled the linux firmware and disabled and enabled intel microcode.

Right now my wireless card is not even detected by my pc as in lspci, lshw, lsusb etc even with sudo.

A while back sometimes wifi card got detected in the midst of usage albeit randomly but would not find or connect to any network and i had 'could not load firmware chunk' errors in dmesg. The wireless card has integrated wifi and bluetooth. the bluetooth works perfectly and i am browsing via bluetooth tethering at moment.
I have disabled and enabled wifi and bluetooth in bios but no change. i have removed battery and left pc unplugged for 4hours but no luck after power on.

I need help on bringing my wifi back as it seems to me that at boot, iwlwifi is not loaded at all.

I have upgraded to latest kernel and even backported kernel to no avail. I am also tried backported linux firmware and worst when i tried my live drive wifi didn't work this time.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 09 Dec 2016 10:53 GMT +0000

Booted last: 09 Dec 2016 00:00 GMT +0000

Script from: 08 Jul 2016 02:16 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.10
Release:    16.10
Codename:   yakkety

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.8.0-27-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 20 21:03:13 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro

##### desktop ###########################

GNOME

##### lspci #############################

00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM [8086:153a] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkPad T440p [17aa:220e]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 04f2:b39a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

iwldvm                233472  0
iwlwifi               229376  1 iwldvm
mac80211              757760  1 iwldvm
cfg80211              581632  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm
wmi                    16384  0

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether <MAC address>  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xe0500000-e0520000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 290166  bytes 18190136 (18.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 290166  bytes 18190136 (18.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether <MAC address>  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0-nic: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether <MAC address>  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

virbr0    no wireless extensions.

virbr0-nic  no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager
    Wicd

Running:

root       847     1  0 Dec08 ?        00:00:02 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         virbr0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           bridge
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceBridge
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         bridge
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/virtual/net/virbr0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       virbr0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    yes
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     virbr0
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       91fc76a8-7ea7-419a-bd4b-0b53cd0f1ab4
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               yes
BRIDGE.SLAVES:                          
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{9}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   91fc76a8-7ea7-419a-bd4b-0b53cd0f1ab4 | virbr0
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.122.1/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.TYPE:                           bt
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceBt
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         bluez
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /org/bluez/hci0/dev_80_19_67_6E_7D_FC
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
BLUETOOTH.CAPABILITIES:                 NAP
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{1}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   9e6a9f5d-9aa6-488c-ba6b-ece265d9ee88 | Pike-BT

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Ethernet Connection I217-LM (ThinkPad T440p)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         e1000e
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 3.2.6-k
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               0.13-3
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0/net/eth0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         virbr0-nic
GENERAL.TYPE:                           tun
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceTun
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         tun
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 1.6
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.REASON:                         41 (The device's existing connection was assumed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/virtual/net/virbr0-nic
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    yes
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     no
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               yes
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=<MAC address>,

[ifupdown]
managed=true

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/BRH-NITA]] (600 root)
[connection] id=BRH-NITA | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=BRH-NITA
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/pike]] (600 root)
[connection] id=pike | type=wifi | permissions=user:arbayong:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=pike
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Africa/Accra (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

virbr0    no frequency information.

virbr0-nic  no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

virbr0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

virbr0-nic  Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[iwldvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-27-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/dvm/iwldvm.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     3A75FAFD9EE2AF56E0994D5
depends:        mac80211,iwlwifi,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-27-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           force_cam:force continuously aware mode (no power saving at all) (bool)

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-27-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-IWL6000G2B_UCODE_API_MAX.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3168-24.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8265-24.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000C--24.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-a0-lc-a0--24.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-a0-jf-a0--24.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-a0-lc-a0--24.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-jf-b0--24.ucode
srcversion:     5916491CB41B355C975C3F8
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-27-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           d0i3_disable:disable d0i3 functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)
parm:           d0i3_timeout:Timeout to D0i3 entry when idle (ms) (uint)
parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-27-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     BDE5CB0CC0A980B65D19934
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-27-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-27-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     F170FED576AF12B070D2E69
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-27-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwldvm]
force_cam: Y

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 1
amsdu_size: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: N
d0i3_disable: Y
d0i3_timeout: 1000
disable_11ac: N
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
lar_disable: N
led_mode: 1
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: 3

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N
options iwlwifi led_mode=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/qemu-system-x86.conf]
options kvm_intel nested=1

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

[/etc/pm/power.d/wireless] (755 root)
iwconfig wlan0 power off

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x8086:0x153a (e1000e)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x8086:0x088f (iwlwifi)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[23540.095629] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Down
[23540.097474] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)

########## wireless info END ############
```